# How to concat all the results of a query in Stream Analytics Query?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have an input from IoT Hub and reference input from Blob Storage.
I want to concat all the results that I found when I match for IoTHubInput.id with BlobStorageInput.id.

Currently the query looks like this:

```
   SELECT Blob
   FROM iothub IoTHub
   JOIN blob Blob
   ON IoTHub.id = Blob.deviceId
```

The result of this query looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "blob": 
    {
        "deviceId": "test001",
        "data": "Sample1"
    }
  },
  {
    "blob": 
    {
        "deviceId": "test002",
        "data": "Sample2"
    }
  },
  {
    "blob": 
    {
        "deviceId": "test003",
        "data": "Sample3"
    }
  },
]
```

It will return 3 message to my output, but I don't want that.

I want all the data in the blob if the id is match, but I actually want them all CONCAT and become an array. For example:

```
[
    {
        "deviceId": "test001",
        "data": "Sample1"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "test002",
        "data": "Sample2"
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "test003",
        "data": "Sample3"
    }
]
```

I searched around the internet and found `GROUP CONCAT` however Stream Analytics does not support that. Is there any other alternative workaround that I can do that will achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce your test data:

[image]

Per my knowledge,there is no `GROUP CONCAT` feature in the ASA. Actually,the output of ASA is an array already.You could verify it in the download result:

[image]

I tested withe a Blob output and it shows as array. If your output produces 3 rows ,I suggest you using [Azure Function Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#azure-functions) to accept the array first then do next transfer steps.

Comment: I see, got it! Will transform further in next steps. Thank you!